# restlet pagination HttpClientHelper start/stop

Tags: java, pagination, restlet

I start off with an initial URI GET request. I get back result along with a link to the next batch of records. I loop thru this until I retrieve all the records. It just seems performance is taking a hit as the logger shows the HttpClientHelper start and stopping after each request. Is this avoidable?

```
Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
ClientResource clientResource;
JsonRepresentation rep;
JSONObject object;
while(nextURI !=null)
{
    clientResource = new ClientResource(nextURI);

    //excessive HttpClientHelper start/stop triggered at next line
    rep = new JsonRepresentation(service.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    clientResource.setNext(client);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Logger shows the following:

> May 13, 2015 9:30:52 AM org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper start
>
> INFO: Starting the HTTP client May 13, 2015 9:30:53 AM
>   org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper start
>
> INFO: Starting the HTTP client May 13, 2015 9:30:53 AM
>   org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper start
>
> INFO: Starting the HTTP client May 13, 2015 9:30:53 AM
>   org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper stop
>
> INFO: Stopping the HTTP client May 13, 2015 9:30:53 AM
>   org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper stop
>
> INFO: Stopping the HTTP client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you call the method `setNext` too late. You need to call it before any HTTP call and right after having created your instance of `ClientResource` to prevent from the client connector to be started at each call.

You can find a sample below:

```
Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://...");
    clientResource.setNext(client);

    Representation representation = clientResource.get();
    (...)
}
```

In this case, the client connector is only started once.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry